# Elite NES. Any way to lower Legal Status / Wanted level

Tags: nes, elite

Title says it all really. I am really enjoying this game but want to know if there is any way in the game to lower my wanted level. I've been an Offender for a while I was hoping it would eventually go back down to Clean

Comment: Just in case anyone else ever wonders this. I kept playing and it eventually went to clean but I'm still unsure if this happens when I went to another galaxy or just from time on good behaviour